# gradle withJavadocJar() and withSourcesJar() for android library

Tags: android, gradle

Is there a way to leverage the new functions `withSourcesJar()` and `withJavadocJar()` for Android library projects? Currently when I try to use it I get:

```
> SourceSet with name 'main' not found.
```

Comment: This topic is discussed in the Android issue tracker. Please have a look at ["Android library plugin should provide a way to build sources jar"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145670440).

Answer (score 5):

With the latest Gradle version 6.0.1, there seems to be no way to use these new methods in Android library projects. Here’s why I believe that’s the case:

- The two methods [`withJavadocJar()`](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPluginExtension.html#withJavadocJar--) and [`withSourcesJar()`](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPluginExtension.html#withSourcesJar--) on the [`java` extension](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java-extension) have the default `main` source set hardcoded, see [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v6.0.1/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/internal/DefaultJavaPluginExtension.java#L111-L112) and [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v6.0.1/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/internal/DefaultJavaPluginExtension.java#L119-L120).
- There are two methods with the same names ([`withJavadocJar()`](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/FeatureSpec.html#withJavadocJar--) and [`withSourcesJar()`](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/FeatureSpec.html#withSourcesJar--)) which can be used in [feature variant declarations](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/feature_variants.html#sec::declare_feature_variants). However, it seems that Android Gradle builds don’t use feature variants, i.e., these methods can’t be used either.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states, that these come from the [JavaPluginExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPluginExtension.html) - but not from Android DSL. So they can only be used in conjunction with `apply plugin: "java"` or `apply plugin: "java-library"`, but not with `apply plugin: "com.android.application"`, `apply plugin: "com.android.library"` and alike. The name of these tasks also suggest that it's common Java (`*.jar`) and not Android (`*.aar`). On Android, this would only make sense for a `*.jar` library, which uses pure Java features, but no Android features at all (which is limited in functionality).

In short, `apply plugin: "java-library"` would permit accessing these.

Answer (score 1):

With Gradle 7.2 I "recreated" `withJavadocJar` and `withSourcesJar` using Gradle Kotlin DSL:

```
val sourceFiles = android.sourceSets.getByName("main").java.getSourceFiles()

tasks.register<Javadoc>("withJavadoc") {
    isFailOnError = false
    dependsOn(tasks.named("compileDebugSources"), tasks.named("compileReleaseSources"))

    // add Android runtime classpath
    android.bootClasspath.forEach { classpath += project.fileTree(it) }

    // add classpath for all dependencies
    android.libraryVariants.forEach { variant ->
        variant.javaCompileProvider.get().classpath.files.forEach { file ->
            classpath += project.fileTree(file)
        }
    }

    source = sourceFiles
}

tasks.register<Jar>("withJavadocJar") {
    archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
    dependsOn(tasks.named("withJavadoc"))
    val destination = tasks.named<Javadoc>("withJavadoc").get().destinationDir
    from(destination)
}

tasks.register<Jar>("withSourcesJar") {
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    from(sourceFiles)
}
```

Put this into your `gradle.build.kts` file and then run `./gradlew withJavadocJar` and `./gradlew withSourcesJar` (or use the tasks to create artifacts for publishing).

`android.sourceSets.getByName("main").java.getSourceFiles()` is the Android specific part to retrieve the "main" source files.